# Any concern using JavaScript prototype object to create Backbone.js default or new methods

Tags: backbone.js, prototype

Which is better performance?

A)

```
var Library = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize = function() {}
});
```

OR

B)

```
var Library = Backbone.View.extend({});
Library.prototype.initialize = function() {}
```

I would think B) should be better for performance since any new instance of the Library object will all inherit and reference to the prototype method.

I would

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the official way:

```
var Library = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {}
});
```

I don't think will be any performance difference, actually (I think) using `prototype` is exactly what *Underscore* does with its `extend()` functionality.

Comment: I agree here, also when you create a new Library object the new object's prototype is the Library object so initialize is reused.

Comment: +1 on no difference in performance. extend simply copies what you provide on the input hash to the object's prototype. What B) does get you is convenience in IDE's such as Eclipse, to find methods more easily, but writing object.prototype.<method> over and over again is pretty tedious.